# Scaling of second data set in ggplot2 line plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, scaling

I want to display the second data set (orange line, "Annual") on the secondary axis because its values are much smaller than the values of the first data set (red line, "Cumulative"). I managed to re-scale the seconary y-axis, but I have problems with re-scaling the second data set because both data sets are read in together and I don't know how to treat the second data set separatly in the code.

The data look like this

Year  Cumulative   Annual
1960  1             1
1961  1             0
1962  1             0
1963  2             1
...
2019  334           9

I would appreciate any constructive comments!

```
library("ggplot2")
library("reshape2")
library("tidyverse")

sec_scale=1/10
datu_sub=data[,c(2,3,1)]
datu=melt(datu_sub,id=c("Year"))
p1<-ggplot(datu)+geom_line(aes(x=Year,y=value,colour=variable),linetype="solid",size=1.1)+
  geom_point(aes(x=Year,y=value,colour=variable),shape=1,size=3,stroke=1.5)+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("darkorange","red"))+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis=sec_axis(~.*sec_scale,name="Annual\n"))
p1<-p1+labs(x="\nYear",y="Cumulative\n")
p1+theme(axis.title.x=element_text(size=18),
         axis.text.x=element_text(size=14),
         axis.title.y=element_text(size=18),
         axis.text.y=element_text(size=14),
         axis.ticks=element_blank(),
         legend.title=element_blank(),
         legend.position=c(0.12,0.89),
         legend.text=element_text(size=14),
         legend.background=element_rect(fill="white",size=0.5,linetype="dotted"))
```

Comment: Would it help if in your `aes()` calls you would use `y=ifelse(variable == "Cumulative", sec_scale, 1) * value)` ? Also, you could make life easier by defining the `aes()` inside the `ggplot()` call instead of in each geom individually, unless there are drawing data from different data.frames.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you describe it in different words. I have tried to perform what you suggested, but am not sure if I got you write.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't fit everything in a comment, so I'll write it as an answer. I had to improvise some data because I don't have a usable sample of yours, but the plotting code should be similar.

```
sec_scale=1/10
# I made up some data because I don't have yours
datu <- data.frame(Year = c(2000:2010, 2000:2010),
                   value = c(rnorm(11, 500, 10), rnorm(11, 5000, 100)),
                   variable = rep(c("Annual", "Cumulative"), each = 11))
```

Now for the plotting, I've removed the `mapping`/`aes()` arguments from the geoms to the main ggplot function and the geoms will inherit these mappings from the main ggplot call.

Next, you'll notice that I've redefined `y = ifelse(variable == "Cumulative, sec_scale, 1) * value`, which will scale all `value`s for which the `variable == "Cumulative"` by the amount in `sec_scale`

```
p1<-ggplot(datu, aes(x = Year, 
                     y = ifelse(variable == "Annual", 1/sec_scale, 1) * value, 
                     colour = variable)) + 
  geom_line(linetype = "solid", size = 1.1) +
  geom_point(shape = 1, size = 3, stroke = 1.5) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("darkorange", "red")) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*sec_scale,name = "Annual\n")) +
  labs(x="\nYear",y="Cumulative\n") + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=18),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=14),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=18),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=14),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = c(0.12,0.89),
        legend.text = element_text(size=14),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill="white",size=0.5,linetype="dotted"))
```

For me the plot looked like this:

[image]

However, I would like to note that a some people dislike secondary axes because they can misleading.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I could manage to lift up the orange line to the wished level, however, both y-axis scaled down using the factor 1/10.

Comment: I wouldn't really know what went wrong unless I have a reproducible example of the data and your plotting code.

Comment: > data
   Year Annual Cumulative
1  1960      1          1
2  1961      0          1
3  1962      0          1
4  1963      0          1
5  1964      0          1
6  1965      0          1
7  1966      0          1
8  1967      1          2
9  1968      0          2
10 1969      0          2
11 1970      0          2
12 1971      0          2
13 1972      1          3
14 1973      0          3
15 1974      1          4
16 1975      1          5
17 1976      0          5
18 1977      0          5
19 1978      0          5
20 1979      4          9

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't programatically parse that data in R, would you mind copy-pasting `dput(head(data))` instead of copy-pasting the output of a print()?

Comment: structure(list(Year = 1960:1965, Annual = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Cumulative = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Ok I figured out that there was a mistake in my code and have updated the answer to correct the mistake

Comment: Beautiful! That was the cue; the graphs are finally arranged as wished. Thank you very much!